# Map the values from 2 dataframe columns to a value in a dict and create a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which looks like below:

```
column_1 column_2
ABC       POI
XYZ       LOK 
DEF       JOY
ASD       QWE
```

I have a dict which has key based on `column_1` and `column_2` and different values like below:

```
d = {('ABC', 'POI'): 'Name1',
     ('XYZ', 'LOK'): 'Name2',
     ('DEF', 'JOY'): 'Name3',
     ('ASD', 'QWE'): 'Name4'}
```

I need to create a different column in the dataframe which maps the value of `column_1` and `column_2` from the dict to the new column. So, the resulted dataframe should look like below:

```
column_1 column_2  Result
ABC       POI       Name1
XYZ       LOK       Name2
DEF       JOY       Name3
ASD       QWE       Name4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, the simplest is to [convert to MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_frame.html) and [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html) you dictionary:

```
df['Result'] = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df).map(d)
```

or to restrict to the two relevant columns:

```
df['Result'] = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df[['column_1','column_2']]).map(d)
```

output:

```
  column_1 column_2 Result
0      ABC      POI  Name1
1      XYZ      LOK  Name2
2      DEF      JOY  Name3
3      ASD      QWE  Name4
```

input:

```
d = {('ABC', 'POI'): 'Name1',
     ('XYZ', 'LOK'): 'Name2',
     ('DEF', 'JOY'): 'Name3',
     ('ASD', 'QWE'): 'Name4'}
```

Comment: @AKSHAY good news, you can consider upvoting/accepting the answers that helped you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with convert dictionary to `Series`:

```
#correct dict
d = {('ABC', 'POI'): 'Name1',
     ('XYZ', 'LOK'): 'Name2',
     ('DEF', 'JOY'): 'Name3',
     ('ASD', 'QWE'): 'Name4'}


df = df.join(pd.Series(d, name='Result'), on=['column_1','column_2'])
print (df)
  column_1 column_2 Result
0      ABC      POI  Name1
1      XYZ      LOK  Name2
2      DEF      JOY  Name3
3      ASD      QWE  Name4
```